# Why are there no highlights?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td7Ar.png)The code in the red box of the picture is not highlighted

Comment: See that red squiggly line under `BasicExample {`?

Comment: Through your hint my problem is solved, thank you.